# Timer function that stops when time <= 0

Tags: javascript, function, timer

I am trying to create a timer that stops at 0 automatically. Right now I can start and stop the timer with buttons, but I am trying to implement a timer function into a game so it will need to stop at 0.

```js
let x;
let time = 15;
// let x = setTimeout(function(){ timer(); }, 1000);

let timer = function() {
    x = setInterval(function() {
        time -= 1
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time + " seconds";
    }, 1000)
}

let stopTimer = function() {
    clearTimeout(x)
}



$("#start").click(function(){
  timer()
 })

$("#stop").click(function(){
  stopTimer()
 })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Timer</h1>
 <p id="timer"></span></p>
 <h2><button id="start">Start Timer</button></h2>
 <h3><button id="stop">Stop Timer</button></h3>

 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your `setInterval` function, add `if (time === 0) ...`

Comment: You literally answered your question when you wrote the title. You need to call `stopTimer` (or just clear the interval) when `time <= 0`

Comment: Yes, I had originally put my if statement outside of the setInterval function so it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
if(time == 0){
    stopTimer();
 }
```

to check when it hits 0 and then calls the stop :)

```js
let x;
let time = 15;
// let x = setTimeout(function(){ timer(); }, 1000);

let timer = function() {
    x = setInterval(function() {
        time -= 1
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time + " seconds";
        if(time == 0){
            stopTimer();
          }
    }, 1000)
}

let stopTimer = function() {
    clearTimeout(x)
}



$("#start").click(function(){
  timer()
 })

$("#stop").click(function(){
  stopTimer()
 })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Timer</h1>
 <p id="timer"></span></p>
 <h2><button id="start">Start Timer</button></h2>
 <h3><button id="stop">Stop Timer</button></h3>

 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval), a way to stop a `setInterval` you already started. See my edited version of your example below.

```js
let x;
let time = 15;
// let x = setTimeout(function(){ timer(); }, 1000);

let timer = function() {
    x = setInterval(function() {
        time -= 1
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = time + " seconds";
        if (time == 0) {
            stopTimer();
        }
    }, 1000)
}

let stopTimer = function() {
    clearInterval(x)
}



$("#start").click(function(){
  timer()
 })

$("#stop").click(function(){
  stopTimer()
 })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Timer</h1>
 <p id="timer"></span></p>
 <h2><button id="start">Start Timer</button></h2>
 <h3><button id="stop">Stop Timer</button></h3>

 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```